# Function to generate incremental weights based on np.select conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, cumulative-sum

Objective: Define function to use flags (1,2,3) as conditions that trigger different weights (.2,.4,0). Output is a new df with the weights only.

The np.select is generating this error:

TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

Image shows desired output as "incremental weight output"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flags = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01'],
                    'flag_1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'flag_2': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_3': [2, 1, 2],
                   'flag_4': [3, 1, 3],
                   'flag_5' : [1, 2, 2],
                   'flag_6': [2, 1, 2],
                   'flag_7': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_8': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_9': [3, 3, 2]})

flags = flags.set_index('Date')

def inc_weights(dfin, wt1, wt2, wt3):
    dfin = pd.DataFrame(dfin.iloc[:,::-1])
    dfout = pd.DataFrame()
    conditions = [1,2,3]
    choices = [wt1,wt2,wt3]
    dfout=np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
    return(dfout.iloc[:,::-1])
inc_weights = inc_weights(flags, .2, .4, 0)
print(inc_weights)
```

[Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MygjM.png)

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: The data are in the flags dataframe which correspond exactly to the input in the image.

Comment: @itprorh66 I've reviewed the minimal reprex rules and tried to tighten this up as much as I can. Thanks for the feedback. For this step, just trying to get the np.select to work for incremental weights only.

Comment: Could you please post you input example as code rather than an image.  It would also help if you posted the expected output as code, but I don't believe that is as important as the input.

Comment: The flags dataframe in the code is the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.select was unnecessary. simple solution using df.replace with a mapping dict.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flags = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01'],
                    'flag_1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'flag_2': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_3': [2, 1, 2],
                   'flag_4': [3, 1, 3],
                   'flag_5' : [1, 2, 2],
                   'flag_6': [2, 1, 2],
                   'flag_7': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_8': [1, 1, 1],
                   'flag_9': [3, 3, 2]})

flags = flags.set_index('Date')

print(flags)

def inc_weights(dfin, wt1, wt2, wt3):
    dfin = pd.DataFrame(dfin.iloc[:,::-1])
    dfout = pd.DataFrame()
    mapping = {1:wt1,2:wt2,3:wt3}
    dfout=dfin.replace(mapping)
    return(dfout.iloc[:,::-1])
inc_weights = inc_weights(flags, .2, .4, 0)
print(inc_weights)
```